# Recyclervew clear viewholder when deleting item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

file with working code to test my issue, you have to add 2 items, then delete any of those and then add a new one to see how the deleted gets on top of the newly addded

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojuyz5g5f3kaz0h/Test.zip?dl=0

I have a problem when deleting an item from the recyclerview, when ever I delete an item, IF I add a new item,  the deleted item will appear in top of the newly added item, how could I get a fresh view or avod this from happening as is a big issue.

this is how i add items from my main activity

```
                            if (!resta || (diff > (3*60*1000)))
                            {
                                Ri.add(dataroot);
                                Integer position = adapter.getItemCount() + 1;
                                adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
                            }
```

here my Adapter

```
public class ComandaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder>{

private Context mContext;

private ArrayList<Integer> lista_entradas = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> lista_fondos = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> lista_postres= new ArrayList<>();

private Boolean primeritem;

private ArrayList<DataRoot> Rir;

private TextView txt_comandas;
private TextView txt_entracola;
private TextView txt_fondocola;
private TextView txt_postrecola;

public ComandaAdapter(Context context, TextView tx_entracola, TextView tx_fondocola, TextView tx_postrecola, TextView tx_comandas, ArrayList<DataRoot> Rir)
{
    this.mContext = context;
    this.txt_comandas = tx_comandas;
    this.txt_entracola = tx_entracola;
    this.txt_fondocola = tx_fondocola;
    this.txt_postrecola = tx_postrecola;
    this.Rir= Rir;
}

@Override
public ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    return new ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ComandaAdapter.ComandaAdapterViewHolder holder, final int position)
{

    DataRoot Rdata = Rir.get(position);
    holder.setdata(Rdata);    


}

public void delete(int position)
{
    Rir.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public class ComandaAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{     
    Button btn_cerrar;

    public ComandaAdapterViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

     btn_cerrar = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_cerrar);

    void setData(final DataRoot Rdata)
    {


         btn_cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                btn_cerrar.setEnabled(false);
                btn_cerrar.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getColorStateList(R.color.cboff));
                updateRetrofitEstadoorden(Rdata.get_id());
                updateRetrofitNrocomanda(Rdata.get_id(), txt_comanda.getText().toString());
                delete(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

    Rdata.gerOrder();
   creaboton():
```

and here my recyler

```
private void setAdapter()
{
    adapter =  new ComandaAdapter(this, txt_entracola, txt_fondocola, txt_postrecola, txt_comandas, Ri);
    recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(-1, Ri.size());//va en 0 supuestamente -1 es default
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(Ri.size()); //ver si hay que cambiar con cada item
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Images to show the problem

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok. Firstly, spanish?? language makes your code extremely difficult to read.  Second, what do you mean by "will appear in top of the newly added item"?  Is it that your view is composed of the UI of both items or that adding a new item caused the deleted one to reappear in the list as a separate view?

Comment: added some pictures to show the issue, and all the methods and structures are in english as java/android are anglish based, nevermind the spanihs for the UI

Comment: Cannot ignore it. It makes the code almost impossible to comprehend for a non spanish speaker as I cannot tell what the code is doing .It isn't just UI, it is methods that control the adapter etc. Impossible to ignore.  As a guess, you are removing the object from your adapter. Are you refreshing the adapter from a data source and replacing the item (I see references to retrofit). If not, perhaps you should simplify your example to the minimal possible code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: ok, let me clean it up, and just to give you and idea of the data, when I press the buttons "CERRAR COMANDA" (close order) in the top of the view it will change the order state in the DB to "zlisto" (zready) and i hava a timer reading the db constantly, any item that comes with the "zready" status will get filtered and as you could probably see in  my delete method, I do Rir.remove(position) deleting that data and then notifyitemitemRemoved(position) should be enough

Comment: where in your code are you adding the new item?

Comment: thats in my mainActivity with this code `if (!resta || (diff > (3*60*1000)))
                                {
                                    Ri.add(dataroot);
                                    Integer position = adapter.getItemCount() + 1;
                                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
                                }`

Comment: Sorry but your sample is not reproducible. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.]

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I add data from the main activity with the method I posted, delete with the method I posted, the rest of the logic and how to do I create the UI does not matters, im miising something in the recyclerview setup or I need to know how to destroy the holder from the deleted item, if i add items after the one getting the deleted trash it works just fine

Comment: It actually does matter. The people you are asking to help you must be able to run your code and see the issue you are presenting. You are leaving out key parts of your code and so it is impossible to reproduce in a test environment in order to locate the issue. It is not enough to post random methods that you think may be relevant. Nobody want to waste time trying to diagnose an issue that may not even be in the code you are posting.

Comment: to be able to run my code you need my whole backend structure which happens to be in my local network with no access to the internet (cant expose my data), I did posted the whole thing and you said that you could NOT read it because it was in spanish, so I cleaned up the data generation methods and only left the recyclerview methods, I dont have 3 days developing, I have 15 years doing it but just recently got to android, so I dont get what the issue is here because the lack of experience with recycelrviews but I know that what i removed was not relevant to the issue

Comment: You do not have to post your entire code base. You need to create an example that illustrates your issue in a concise and reproducible way. Maybe just the act of doing this will make it obvious to yo where you are going wrong. I do it by creating a test project that mimics my issue.

Comment: yes im in the process of doing that, will get back here with a report

Comment: I have created a small demo project of recyclerview for you. Perhaps you can learn from it.https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6768304/WebLinks/Test.zip

Comment: very appreciate it. gonna check it up

Comment: hello, based in your Test.zip file, i have managed to reproduce the exact same issue, here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojuyz5g5f3kaz0h/Test.zip?dl=0 you just have to add 2 items, delete any of those and then add a new and you will see that the deleted item will be placed on top of the newly added, as i said my data is random so everytime you add an item it generates a random amount of buttons BUT if you add just one the thing will hapen anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Recyclerview in a very non standard way.  The issue you are seeing is because the views are being recycled (as they should be in a Recyclerview) but you are not clearing out the items from the previous view.

The problem in in this method:

```
public void setData(String value) {

        container.removeAllViews();  // Remove all previously added views

        textview.setText(value);

        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(5 - 1) + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++) {
            be = new Button(mContext);
            be.setText("Boton " + i);
            be.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(240, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            container.addView(be);
        }

    }
```

By calling `container.addView(be)`, you are manually adding extra views to the views that the Recyclerview creates. When you remove these views, they are cached and reused the next time you press "Add".  The problem is that the cached view still contains all of the manually added views so you are then adding more views under the existing ones.

As you can see in the code above, i added `container.removeAllViews();` which removes the views that were added previously ensuring that "Container" is empty before you start adding your extra views to it.

Also, unless you have a very specific reason for doing so, I would removes these lines as I believe you are hurting performance by having them:

```
list.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(-1, index);
list.setItemViewCacheSize(index);
```

Comment: would you marry me? xD, i feel like i love you hehehe... thanks man

Comment: Only if you are pretty

Comment: hahaha , thats what you say to all of them? xD, thanks again man, this issue was killimg me for the past 3 days, my head hurts..

Comment: any ideas of why it gets desyncs??? use the TEST.zip and check. remove the 2 lines you said and add 50 items, go back and forward and see the data changing

Comment: Not at computer now sorry.

Comment: It is doing what you asked it to do and adding a random number of buttons to the view. When an item goes off screen, its view is cached. When you scroll it back onscreen, it is recreated but as the code to recreate causes a random number of buttons to be added, then the data changes because the  random number you get this time is different to the random number you got the first time the item was created.

Comment: Add `Log.d("TEST","Creating View " + value);` above the `RemoveAllViews` line I added previously then watch your logcat as you scroll

Comment: See this project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6768304/WebLinks/Test2.zip It still creates a random number of buttons but it stores the number in the order details so the same order always has the same number.